# Add a new row to calculate overround in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, excel, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hey I'm creating a plugin for Chrome to calculate the overrounds from races on oddschecker. It essentially divides 1 by the odds in the cell and then calculates the perceived chance of it occurring according to the bookmakers

In an excel sheet I've done it like this: [image: example of what I've done in excel]

The above example adds another row to the bottom called the odds payout calculation, this adds the percentages together and gives an overround

=SUM((1/E2)+(1/E4)+(1/E5)+(1/E6)+(1/E7)+(1/E8)).

These pages on oddschecker all have different amounts of horses, so an if else statement may have to be used for this, but I can worry about that later.

When editing the html of the page I add in a new row like this:

```
<tr class="eventTableRow bgc"><td style="display: none;"          
id="15183669200_best">10000</td><td style="display: none;" 
id="15183669200_name">Payout Percentage</td><td>6</td><td>8</td><td></td>
<td class="sel nm"><a class="popup selTxt" target="_blank" title="" data-name="Le Deluge">== Odds Payout Calculation ==</a><div class="tips-box"></div></td><td id="15183669200_B3" class="o np"></td>
<td id="15183669200_SK" class="o np"></td>
<td id="15183669200_BX" class="o np"></td>
<td id="15183669200_BY" class="o bgc co">SP</td>
<td id="15183669200_FR" class="o np"></td>
<td id="15183669200_SO" class="o np"></td>
<td id="15183669200_VC" class="o np"></td>
<td id="15183669200_PP" class="o np"></td>
<td id="15183669200_SJ" class="o np"></td>
<td id="15183669200_EE" class="oi bgc co">12</td>
<td id="15183669200_LD" class="o np"></td>
<td id="15183669200_CE" class="o np"></td>
<td id="15183669200_WH" class="o np">8</td>
<td id="15183669200_WN" class="o np">SP</td>
<td id="15183669200_FB" class="oo bgc co">11</td>
<td id="15183669200_WA" class="o np"></td>
<td id="15183669200_BB" class="oi bgc co">9</td>
<td id="15183669200_TI" class="o np">SP</td>
<td id="15183669200_RB" class="o np"></td>
<td id="15183669200_RD" class="oi bgc co">12</td>
<td class="wo wo-col"></td>
<td id="15183669200_BF" class="o np"></td>
<td id="15183669200_BD" class="o np"></td></tr>
```

In the text box

Here is an example of how it looks using this
[image: example of how it will look]
http://www.oddschecker.com/horse-racing/2015-06-30-chepstow/18:10/winner

Is there a way in which I can calculate the overround at the bottom through html/javascript?

Comment: _"Is there a way in which I can calculate the overround at the bottom through html/javascript?"_ Yes. Yes, there is. You'll need to narrow down the question.

Comment: Ok, I might just ask how that calculation can be done in a more basic query. Perhaps went over the top here.

Comment: I mean, there are many aspects of the problem, and it's unclear what you're having trouble with: extracting data? algorithm for calculating? outputting data?

Comment: Algo for calculating through javascript and then outputting it in the new row.

Comment: So you have the data extracted already? If yes, show how: this will give a starting point for the algorithm to know how you organize it.

Comment: I wasn't looking to extract data, just to do a calculation with the data already on the web page, or is that not feasible without extracting?

Comment: You need to find the data on the webpage and read it into JavaScript code. That's what I mean. Those 3 things I mentioned above are all quite separate problems. If you need help with everything, you probably need to split this question into several ones.